# How do I get these link buttons to display properly in this PHP code?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to add some additional links to a php script.

Here is the original code:

```
        <div id="content-left">
        <h4>Recent Work</h4>
        <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2&cat=-8,-52,-53,-54'); ?>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="home-blog-feed">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(130, 70, true)); ?>

            <div class="home-feed-right">
            <span class="home-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="home-description"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Caption', true); ?></span>
            <span class="home-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">View Gallery</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <a href="http://www.mysite.com/blog/" class="button feed">View More</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That code is producing the following output:

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to add two additional buttons below the 'View More' button. When I add the code, the buttons appear at the top of the parent div and end up appearing behind 'Recent Work' and the first picture.

I'm new with php, any help as to why it is not appearing below the 'View More' button would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using echo command and '\n' to create breaks, but it doesn't take effect.

Also, here is an example of the coded button I'm attempting to add below the 'View More' button:

```
<a class="large-button" href="http://www.mysite.com/my-specified-page/">View Page</a>
```

Here is the page:

http://www.aimeehurstphotography.com/wedding-photography-2/

Here is the CSS for the left content output:

```
#content-left {
width:330px;
float:left;
height:auto;
padding:0;
margin:0;}

.home-blog-feed {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    margin-bottom:7px;}
.home-blog-feed img {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin:0 18px 0 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:#CCC solid 1px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFFFFF;}

    .home-feed-right {
        width:170px;
        float:left;}

    .home-title {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;}
    .home-description {
        font-weight:normal;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        padding:0;
        display:block;
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
        color:#666;
    }
    .home-link a {
        font-weight:normal;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        display:block;
        color:#008080;
    }
    .home-link a:hover {
        color:#960;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the resulting HTML along with your CSS -- or at least provide a link to the page if it's live. Showing some basic PHP with multiple subroutines referenced is usually not very useful to detect styling issues.

Comment: Here is the page in question:

http://www.aimeehurstphotography.com/wedding-photography-2/

Comment: Where exactly are the links that are behaving unexpectedly, please?

Comment: They are not added to the code, as it was not displaying properly.

I'm trying to move the 'View Gallery' and 'Pricing' buttons (which are created through HTML in the wordpress page editor) below the content-left feed which is generated through php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a float problem. Try adding a

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

between the two buttons. Of course, you can and should add a stylesheet class for that purpose.

Comment: I believe D.Muller means between the "View More" button and the other two buttons when he says "between the two buttons." Sorry for interfering, @D.Muller, though!

Comment: That seems to produce the result I'm looking for, so far!

How would I make it into a style class that displays it properly? Just adding the code you provided to the php code I have above, produces the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the number of posts you're fetching. I saw no problems when adding another 2 items on the page.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=4&cat=-8,-52,-53,-54'); ?>
```

Comment: I don't mean to be a rude complainer but, seriously?

Comment: I'm confused on how that helps me add buttons below the 'View More' button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:
`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/blog/" class="button feed" style="float:left">View More</a><br />
        <a class="large-button" href="http://www.mysite.com/my-specified-page/" style="float:left">View Page</a>`